# Getting error when using WPF CSLA Remote server

Tags: wpf, csla

I am running a WPF app with a remote server setup but getting "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request" .

This is definitely a request size issue since I tried reducing the data size being sent and the call worked fine.  From my configuration it looks like I have 2 Gigs set up, but it behaves like only the default limit (something like 65000 bytes) is being used.  I am thinking there is something wrong with my configuration.

Any help would be appreciated!

Mark.

I have a remote Server set up using WCF web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingSettings" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfPortal">
    <endpoint contract="Csla.Server.Hosts.IWcfPortal" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

And my app.config on the client is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingSettings" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint name="WcfDataPortal" address="http://alcatraz.dev/AlcatrazHost/WcfPortal.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Csla.Server.Hosts.IWcfPortal" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingSettings" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set quotas on the client and the server, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a connection timeout?  2GB is a huge amount of data to want to submit via a web service.

You might want to look at alternative means to move the data across the network such as a file share, SFTP, etc.